# Applying down-payments

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to ask customers for 1/3 down from their total bill before work can be performed. How do I calculate this?! For example, if a total bill was $688.96, how do I calculate to show their down payment amount that they need to pay?

Comment: If the down payment is $1/3$ of the total, then you divide the total by 3.

Comment: Using all caps is considered shouting on the internet, and is quite rude. Please don't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

If their bill is $x$ dollars, their down payment is $1/3 \times x$ of their entire bill.

So to calculate this it will be $x/3$ = Down Payment

Example being, if a total bill was $688.96$, then the down payment is $\$688.96/3= \$229.65$

Comment: $.3 \neq 1/3$, though.

Comment: Haha, oops. fixed.